# Cut raster by pixels in GDAL

Tags: python, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, array

i've some georeferenced images that have the size of 1280 X 960. I need to cut the outer pixels to have a size of 1220 X 900 (i need to cut 30 pixel for each borders).

Can i do this using GDAL or a python script using numpy array?

I try using Gdal warp:
`gdalwarp -to SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM -te 30 30 1250 930 
input.tif output.tif`

But in this case the result is a not georeferenced image.

Comment: Suggest using gdal_translate with "srcwin" argument, which defines a window in pixel index: [-srcwin xoff yoff xsize ysize], so you probably want `-srcwin 30 30 1220 900`

Answer (score 4):

Gdal_translate can do that with -srcwin https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html.

> -srcwin     Selects a subwindow from the source image for copying based on pixel/line location.

The minimal command would be

```
gdal_translate -srcwin 30 30 1220 900 input.tif output.tif
```

Instead of using gdal_translate binary you can use it also as a library in Python https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc59.1_utilities_as_a_library.

The order of terms is

- offset from the top-left corner in x-direction (width)
- offset from the top-left corner in y-direction (height)
- size of the output image in x-direction
- size of the output image in y-direction

Comment: I tried it out and the argument is **-srcwin 30 30 900 1220**. It works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, it works!!! thanks

Answer (score 2):

In documentation for gdalwarp command:

https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html

there is an example where is pointed out that options in your command are precisely used for un-georeferenced images and it is also necessary a **cutline** as csv file. So, for georeferenced images, you only need to add or to rest 30*(Pixel Size) to **xmin ymin xmax ymax** values. These values can easily get in **Raster Properties -> Information -> Extent, Pizel Size**.

To test my approach, I created a random raster with a dimension of 1280x960; whose values for extent and Pixel Size were as follows:

> Extent:
>   354971.3488602247089148,4378722.8366580698639154 : 426000.5231592403142713,4473428.4023900907486677
>
> Pizel Size:
>   73.98872322814125368

For new cut raster:

```
xmin + 30*(Pixel Size): 354971.3488602247089148 + 2219.661696844 = 357191.010557069
ymin + 30*(Pixel Size): 4378722.8366580698639154 + 2219.661696844 = 4380942.498354914
xmax - 30*(Pixel Size): 426000.5231592403142713 - 2219.661696844 = 423780.861462396
ymax - 30*(Pixel Size): 4473428.4023900907486677 - 2219.661696844 = 4471208.740693247
```

So, my complete command is:

```
gdalwarp -overwrite -te 357191,010557069 4380942,498354914 423780,861462396 4471208,740693247 random.tif out.tif
```

When I ran in Console above command, I got following result:

```
zeito@zeito-pc:~/pyqgis_data$ gdalwarp -overwrite -te 357191,010557069 4380942,498354914 423780,861462396 4471208,740693247 random.tif out.tif
Creating output file that is 900P x 1220L.
Processing random.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

where it can be observed that raster dimension is as expected: 900P x 1220L.

In the following image are the original and the resulting raster. Resulting raster (with pseudocolor symbology for better identification) was effectively cut 30 pixels for each border.

[image]